# Combine Windows CMD BAT files

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to build a .bat file that will run an executable Java SpringBoot web app jar file (keeping the cmd window open so that I can verify it started cleanly and close it/kill the process when I'm done), then wait 10 seconds to give the app time to start, then finally open it's URL in my web browser.

I've been able to get my intended functionality by breaking it down into two .bat files. The code I have below does what I want (except the echo message is repeated, but that's not a big deal).

I'd like to know how I can achieve the same functionality within a single .bat file.

I have launch.bat:

```
start wait.bat
java -jar C:\dev_tools\myapp.jar
```

which calls wait.bat:

```
echo Waiting for app to start before launching browser...
timeout 10
start http://localhost:8013/myapp/ && exit
```

Comment: You have stated that the first code 'calls `wait.bat`', but it doesn't, it 'starts' it. Change `start wait.bat` to `call "wait.bat"` to do that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the combined script is called `launch.bat`, put `if not "%~1" == "" goto :JUMP` on top, then the contents of `launch.bat` but with the first line changed to `start launch.bat #`, then place `goto :EOF`, then `:JUMP`, then the contents of `wait.bat`:

```cmd
if not "%~1" == "" goto :JUMP
start launch.bat #
java -jar C:\dev_tools\myapp.jar
goto :EOF

:JUMP
echo Waiting for app to start before launching browser...
timeout 10
start http://localhost:8013/myapp/ && exit
```

When you now start `launch.bat`, it first checks if there is an argument, which should not be the case initially; so the first `start` command line is reached where the script executes itself, but with an argument (`#`) this time; the initially executed instance continues executing the rest until `goto :EOF` is reached, which terminates execution.
The recursively called instance will immediately continue execution at label `:JUMP`, where the code of the original `wait.bat` script is placed.

Answer (score 0):

I think, this should work:

```
@echo off
start "MyApp" java.exe -jar C:\dev_tools\myapp.jar
echo Waiting for app to start before launching browser...
%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe 10
start http://localhost:8013/myapp/
```

`java.exe` is started as separate process running parallel to `cmd.exe` instance processing this batch file.

So immediately after starting `java.exe` the information line is output by `cmd.exe` in initially opened console window.

Then `timeout` is executed to wait 10 seconds before finally the application is started with the HTTP URL.

Finally `cmd.exe` finishes processing the batch file as reading end of batch file which results in terminating the `cmd.exe` if started with option `/C` as done on double clicking on a batch file.

The Java application started as separate process keeps running independent on termination of `cmd.exe` processing the batch file.

I hope this is what you want.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `start /?`
- `timeout /?`

Comment: This doesn't quite work, the app doesn't actually start, I just see a cmd window for the jar open then quickly close, so I'm not exactly sure what the issue is. But thanks for the attempt.